# Fourteen buttons with hover effects

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

I have just started learning coding and am trying to clean up a website that I am making. Everything is functional, but I imagine there is a better way write everything that is there, because a good chunk of it is repeated each time (the part with mouseover and mouseout) Is there a way to create a command like mouseover that applies to all images/buttons?

```html
<div class="portfolioFilter">
   
   <p style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wK8ruJOkmgUaadrdB-fhBA2z-2I4EL5Yvf2nK68xpxU/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image"
onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wK8ruJOkmgUaadrdB-fhBA2z-2I4EL5Yvf2nK68xpxU/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".MJ"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1MAeTP02X9cQrGoTnCZX_nF2l7xksiWjYb30drGhuspM/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image"
    onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1MAeTP02X9cQrGoTnCZX_nF2l7xksiWjYb30drGhuspM/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".1"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KdfLMuWGRdzjh_5Yqtmct_l_NulVui7gxZJ3IGTgpaQ/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image"
    onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KdfLMuWGRdzjh_5Yqtmct_l_NulVui7gxZJ3IGTgpaQ/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".2"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/184ePlol0z8sSK0xIrpJVoyIR8RpiFtLUwmHT_6J1KsU/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image"
    onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/184ePlol0z8sSK0xIrpJVoyIR8RpiFtLUwmHT_6J1KsU/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".3"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fPBVg5ER1j6RrIX4byEwkBkVQuoJacbVAV1b67vfZOI/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" 
    onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fPBVg5ER1j6RrIX4byEwkBkVQuoJacbVAV1b67vfZOI/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".4"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/145o3U6239DLj_P5NJliHWt9opoejc05eGrLs0QK-Pr4/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/145o3U6239DLj_P5NJliHWt9opoejc05eGrLs0QK-Pr4/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".5"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fZUg-gh6itL3lapF88bgATtAMbd5788Igcq7YYfNL74/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fZUg-gh6itL3lapF88bgATtAMbd5788Igcq7YYfNL74/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".6"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/157JSA7Xjcm9GHIEOMXZYpxOWHt0nlQWij_aVy-YRWbg/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/157JSA7Xjcm9GHIEOMXZYpxOWHt0nlQWij_aVy-YRWbg/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".7"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1XGCLM_jvN2oVWolc7_kCVYXn8AZlJeRjpTaTRwcRA9A/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1XGCLM_jvN2oVWolc7_kCVYXn8AZlJeRjpTaTRwcRA9A/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".8"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1yeJtaOPxVcajcSi4_47RlwxY9eZUWIOY4zUy5_nRTYI/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1yeJtaOPxVcajcSi4_47RlwxY9eZUWIOY4zUy5_nRTYI/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
    
<a href="#" data-filter=".9"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1czPnvn4MAOpRJ45qx6qi5WQndxzyBqK302SuenVHlKA/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1czPnvn4MAOpRJ45qx6qi5WQndxzyBqK302SuenVHlKA/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".10"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1GBUL9KuiebtzvpZwO4c9cOCr-9qry7bXc91UaJK6eRQ/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1GBUL9KuiebtzvpZwO4c9cOCr-9qry7bXc91UaJK6eRQ/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".11"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1L1wfQWtHGsFsnWMWkTJK1qAKq7jt1JgiWiGCobPQ46E/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1L1wfQWtHGsFsnWMWkTJK1qAKq7jt1JgiWiGCobPQ46E/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>

<a href="#" data-filter=".12"><img src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IcgefHKcMCxEs6ZUjpVhisnxLE9hZ92zZKqLyy597W4/pub?w=40&h=40" alt="image" onmouseover="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40';"
    onmouseout="this.src='https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IcgefHKcMCxEs6ZUjpVhisnxLE9hZ92zZKqLyy597W4/pub?w=40&h=40';"></a>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The initial load seems to be slow, I wonder if that's because the images are out on google docs.

Comment: Not sure why it seems to be slow, they seem to pop up quickly for me, but it could because it's my account google account... here is the website: http://joetnick.weebly.com/maths.html

Comment: Why would you host images off-site via Google Docs rather than on your own domain?

Comment: [Disconnect](https://disconnect.me/) tells me that site makes 21 requests to Google that use 200 KB of bandwidth.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually do this entirely in CSS with no need for JavaScript.  You just have to switch to using `background-image` instead of an image within the anchor and apply a unique class (or id) to each element to target them in your CSS.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
.star {
  background-image: url(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wK8ruJOkmgUaadrdB-fhBA2z-2I4EL5Yvf2nK68xpxU/pub?w=40&h=40);
}
.mj {
  background-image: url(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1MAeTP02X9cQrGoTnCZX_nF2l7xksiWjYb30drGhuspM/pub?w=40&h=40)
}
.one {
  background-image: url(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1KdfLMuWGRdzjh_5Yqtmct_l_NulVui7gxZJ3IGTgpaQ/pub?w=40&h=40);
}
.button:hover {
  background-image: url(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1Sb4sO71xOTgg3nyfJ1PmbqAC_ucTDsEqDm2CiZFyDA8/pub?w=40&h=40);
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioFilter">

  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="button star current"></a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".MJ" class="button mj"></a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".1" class="button one"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't be using images for text, nor should you be using JavaScript at all.

The images aren't semantically relevant; they are just for styling.  By using text, you'll make your site workable on text-only devices, as well as screen readers.  Furthermore, it's actually *easier* to maintain your website if it's HTML text, rather than text that has been burned into 14 images.  You just need two background images:

Blank circle: [image: Blank circle]          Flower: [image: Flower in circle]

Then, the styling and hover effect should be done using just CSS.

```css
div.portfolioFilter {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
}

div.portfolioFilter a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/XJ2EC.png); /* Blank circle */
    color: rgb(214,79,83);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.portfolioFilter a:hover {
    background-image: url(//i.stack.imgur.com/odFkQ.png); /* Flower */
    color: transparent;
}
div.portfolioFilter a[data-filter="*"],
div.portfolioFilter a[data-filter=".MJ"] {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioFilter">
    <a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">Tout</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".MJ">M/J</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".1">1</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".2">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".3">3</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".4">4</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".5">5</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".6">6</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".7">7</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".8">8</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".9">9</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".10">10</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".11">11</a>
    <a href="#" data-filter=".12">12</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just an additional comment as the two previous have done well.

**Encoding small images with base64**

There is a misconception that using base 64 encoded images in HTML and CSS is inefficient.

Not True.

The general conscientious is the because base 64 adds about 15% more bytes to the image. It does before the HTML is gzip encoded.

I created two html pages. I used just one div with the `.star{background-image:`

One with the Google link to the image (starG.html), and
one with the image in the CSS using base 64 encoding (star64.html).

I tested both pages on webpagetest.org

### star64: 0.4KB Less bytes, and 243% faster than startG.

**starG:  Both HTML and PNG:**

```
Bytes In (downloaded): 2.1 KB
Total Load Time 0.732s
```

**star64:**

```
Bytes In (downloaded): 1.7 KB
Total Load Time:  0.301s
```

---

Below are actual numbers from webpagetest.org.

when the content download is less than 1ms webpagetest reports nothing.  The numbers for these two figure I got from my Browser.

---

### starG.html

[image: starG]

**NOTE: 3rd Line above is favicon.ico**

```
URL: starG.html
Start Offset: 0.102 s
DNS Lookup: 40 ms
Initial Connection: 62 ms
Time to First Byte: 68 ms
Content Download: ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 0.5 KB

 URL: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wK8ruJOkmgUaadrdB-fhBA2z-2I4EL5Yvf2nK68xpxU/pub?w=40&h=40
Start Offset: 0.330 s
DNS Lookup: 31 ms
Initial Connection: 34 ms
SSL Negotiation: 62 ms
Time to First Byte: 309 ms
Content Download: 5 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 2.1 KB
Total Load Time 0.732s
```

**NOTE: SSL added 62ms**
This is actually very fast SSL negotiation. I have a client on a GoDaddy VPS, and typical SSL is well over 500ms.

Both HTML and PNG: Total Bytes In (downloaded): 2.1 KB

---

### star64.html

[image: star64]

**NOTE: 2nd Line above is favicon.ico**

```
URL: star64.html
Start Offset: 0.104 s
DNS Lookup: 40 ms
Initial Connection: 64 ms
Time to First Byte: 68 ms
Content Download: 0.425 ms
Bytes In (downloaded): 1.7 KB
Total Load Time:  0.301s
```

---

### HTML starG.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Star</title>
<style type="text/css">
.star {height:40px;width:40px;
  background-image: url(https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1wK8ruJOkmgUaadrdB-fhBA2z-2I4EL5Yvf2nK68xpxU/pub?w=40&h=40);}

</style></head><body><div class="star"></div></body></html>
```

---

### HTML star64.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><title>Star</title>
<style type="text/css">
.star {width:40px;height:40px;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');}
</style></head><body><div class="star"></div></body></html>
```

**star64 as Snippet:**
Both starG and star64 render exactly the same.

```css
.star {width:40px;height:40px;
background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');}
```

```html
<div class="star"></div>
```